# Naive-Bayes and Multi-Class classifier are returning integers. Data team says they should be probabilities

Tags: integer, naivebayes, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset with 100 columns, divided into training and testing sets, 40,000 and 10,000 rows, respectively.  My task was to train and test two classifiers, and to report the results by providing CSV files with the predictions for the target variable (a 0 or a 1).  My problem is that my models are returning integers, and the principal rejected my answer, saying that the numbers should be probabilities, not integers.

I cleaned both training and testing sets, naming the training set 'goodtrain' and the testing set 'goodtest'. I then ran SelectKBest on goodtrain to take the 10 best features, and then used train_test_split to further divide goodtrain into train and test subsets.  I then trained a model using Naive Bayes and multi-class classification and tested it on the test subset.  Once the classifiers were trained, I used them on goodtest and saved the results as CSV files.

```
# Naive Bayes, with and without 5-fold cross-validation

# Create a Naive Bayes object
gnb = GaussianNB()

# Train the classifer and form a predictive model
modelNB = gnb.fit(trainX, trainY.values.ravel())
predNB = modelNB.predict(testX)

# Test the model and report the accuracy score
print("Naive-Bayes accuracy: ", round(accuracy_score(testY, predNB, normalize=True)*100, 2), "\b%")

# With 5-fold cross-validation
scoreNBcv05 = cross_val_score(modelNB, trainX, trainY.values.ravel(), cv=5)
print("Cross-validated Naive Bayes accuracy, 5 folds: ", round(scoreNBcv05.mean()*100,2), "\b%")
```

Naive-Bayes accuracy:  79.92%
Cross-validated Naive Bayes accuracy, 5 folds:  79.52%

```
# Multi-classification model with logistic regression

# Create a LR object
lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

# Train the algorithm and form a predictive model
modelLR = lr.fit(trainX, trainY.values.ravel()) 
predLR = modelLR.predict(testX)

# Test the model and report accuracy score
print("Multi-classification with Logistic Regression accuracy: ", round(accuracy_score(testY, predLR, normalize=True)*100, 2), "\b%")

# 5 fold cross-validation:
scoreLRcv05 = cross_val_score(modelLR, trainX, trainY.values.ravel(), cv=5)
print("Cross-validated Multi-class with Logistic Regression accuracy, 5 folds: ", round(scoreLRcv05.mean()*100,2), "\b%")
```

Multi-classification with Logistic Regression accuracy:  80.1%
Cross-validated Multi-class with Logistic Regression accuracy, 5 folds:  79.59%

```
# Generate prediction for original test set using Naive Bayes

# Train the classifer and form a predictive model
modelNB = gnb.fit(trainX, trainY)
results1 = modelNB.predict(goodtest)

# Save the results as results1.csv
np.savetxt("results1.csv", results1, delimiter=",")
```

```
# Generate prediction for original test set using multi-class logistic regression

# Train the algorithm and form a predictive model
modelLR = lr.fit(trainX, trainY) 
results2 = modelLR.predict(goodtest)

# Save the results as results2.csv
np.savetxt("results2.csv", results2.astype(int), delimiter=",")
```

I didn't get an error, but the models predicted single columns of 0s and 1s, which the principal said was incorrect.  I realize this question shows a lack of understanding about how these classifiers worked, but I'd appreciate any insight into what I'm overlooking.

Comment: I figured it out.  I used .predict_proba instead of .predict.

Answer (score 0):

Using .predict_proba instead of .predict solved the issue.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.